# datatables causing slick slide height to be huge

Tags: jquery, datatables, slick.js

This is a strange situation I am experiencing. I am using Datatables in a second slide of slick. There are many rows in the datatable and this causes the height of the slide to be huge (the bottom dots of the slide position, which slide I am on, is showing at the bottom of the page). Therefore any other HTML element is showing after this immense blank space at the bottom of the page.

I added paging to the datatable which only shows the first 10 rows. However this hasn't changed the size of the slide. It is as if the slide height is setting itself for the un-paged datatable height rather than the paged datatable height.

Have been trying to solve for hours with zero luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your *DataTable* within a `div` of fixed height and let it scroll on excessing limit:

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;height:500px;">

 <!-- DataTable contents goes below -->

</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks ,was hours of looking. Feel like its a bit of a workaround but it brings the slide just after the table. Almost feel like there is a bug in Datatables or slide. But thank you!

Comment: @Elad I have faced similar issue earlier with Slick.